# HTML, how to properly write image formatting and tables code for a MS Outlook newsletter?

Tags: html, css, image, outlook, newsletter

I am doing a newsletter where most of the recipients will use outlook and I have encountered 2 major problems.

First that depending on a computer I get a differently displayed image like in the screenshots:

When I change the width value of the image to 750 it works on my computer but is too wide on my colleagues': https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZxLf.png

Reversed situation happens when I change the value to 600(how it should be) it's too narrow for me and perfect for her: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aFPGo.

here is the code:

```html
<table class="baemail320resize" align="center" border="0" cellpadding="" cellspacing="0" style="height:350; max-height: 350px; max-width:600px; border-bottom: none!important;border-right: none !important;" width="600" height="350">
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="#333333" height="350" background="http://img.anpdm.com/BalticDevelopmentForum/background-100.jpg" style="display:block; background-repeat: no-repeat; padding: 0;" valign="middle;" width="auto"><!--[if gte mso 9]>
  <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="width: 600px; height: 350px;">
    <v:fill type="tile" src="http://img.anpdm.com/BalticDevelopmentForum/background-100.jpg" color="#333333" />
    <v:textbox inset="0,0,0,0">
  <![endif]-->
      <table class="baemail320resize" valign="middle" align="center"  border="0" cellpadding="" cellspacing="15" style="height:350px; vertical-align:middle; max-height: 350px; max-width:600px; border-bottom: none; border-right: none ;" width="600">
               <tr>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="center" href="www.bdforum.org" ><img align="center" alt="LOGO" height="47px" href="www.bdforum.org" src="http://img.anpdm.com/BalticDevelopmentForum/Asset-2.png" style="display:block;" width="88px"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="center" valign="middle"><font style="font-weight:none;font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; color: #ffffff ;text-decoration:none; ">
            <anpa href="##TellAFriend##" style="color: #fffff6 ; text-decoration:none;">FORWARD &nbsp;&nbsp;</anpa>
            <anpa href="http://www.anpdm.com/form/4743504075464B5943/414358407446455F4571" style="color: #fffff6 ; text-decoration:none;text-align: center;">SUBSCRIBE &nbsp;&nbsp;</anpa>
            <anpa href="##OptOutAll##" style="color: #fffff6; text-decoration:none;">UNSUBSCRIBE</anpa>
            <br>
            </font></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="center" valign="middle" width="600" style="padding: 1em;"><font style="font-weight:none;font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 20px; color: #ffffff !important;">
            <anpa href="http://www.bdforum.org" style="color: #fffff6;">BALTIC DEVELOPMENT FORUM</anpa>
            </font></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="center" style="font-weight:none;font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; color: #ffffff !important; ">LATEST BDF NEWS ESPECIALLY FOR YOU</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="center"><table role="presentation" aria-hidden="true" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center" width="160" style="margin: auto;">
              <tr>
                <td style="border-radius: 30px; background: #d1003e; text-align: center;"><a href="http://www.bdforum.org" style="background-color:#d1003e;border: 5px solid #d1003e; border-radius:30px;color:#ffffff;display:block;font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px;line-height:25px;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;"> <span style="color:#ffffff;">WEBSITE</span> </a></td>
              </tr>
            </table></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      
      <!--[if gte mso 9]>
    </v:textbox>
  </v:rect>
  <![endif]--></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><img src="http://customers.anpdm.com/shared/images/pixel.gif" width="1" height="20" style="display:block;"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Moreover, there is another case with a social media panel for the newsletter where it works on mine (it keeps the width as I set it in the code):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/iWbIn.png

but does not on hers(its too wide and the icons grow):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/NM0pS.png

the code:

```html
<table class="baemail320resize" align="center" border="0" cellpadding="" cellspacing="0" style="max-height:60px; max-width:600px; border-bottom: none!important;border-right: none !important;" width="600" height="auto">
  <tr>
    <td><table class="baemail320resize" valign="middle" align="center"  border="0" cellpadding="" cellspacing="0" style="max-height:60px; vertical-align:middle; max-width:600px; border-bottom: none; border-right: none ;" width="600">
        <tr>
          <td align="center" valign="middle" class="baemailwidthcollapse"><img src="http://customers.anpdm.com/shared/images/pixel.gif"       align="center" link="" height="1" width="20" style="max-height:1; max-width: 20px;"></td>
          <!-- EMPTY -->
          
          <td align="center" valign="middle" href="https://www.facebook.com/bdforum.org"><img src="http://img.anpdm.com/BalticDevelopmentForum/Asset1x3.png" href="https://www.facebook.com/bdforum.org" link="https://www.facebook.com/bdforum.org" alt="FACEBOOK" align="center" height="auto" width="45%" style="max-height:60px; max-width: 60px;"></td>
          <!-- FACEBOOK -->
          <td align="center" valign="middle" href="https://twitter.com/bdforumorg"><img src="http://img.anpdm.com/BalticDevelopmentForum/Asset2x3.png" href="https://twitter.com/bdforumorg" link="https://twitter.com/bdforumorg" alt="TWITTER" align="center" height="auto" width="45%" style="max-height:60px; max-width: 60px;"></td>
          <!-- TWITTER -->
          <td align="center" valign="middle" href="https://www.youtube.com/user/balticdevforum"><img src="http://img.anpdm.com/BalticDevelopmentForum/Asset3x3.png" href="https://www.youtube.com/user/balticdevforum" link="https://www.youtube.com/user/balticdevforum" alt="YOU TUBE" align="center" height="auto" width="45%" style="max-height:60px; max-width: 60px;"></td>
          <!-- YOU TUBE -->
          <td align="center" valign="middle" href="https://www.flickr.com/photos/baltic-development-forum"><img src="http://img.anpdm.com/BalticDevelopmentForum/Asset4x3.png" href="https://www.flickr.com/photos/baltic-development-forum" link="https://www.flickr.com/photos/baltic-development-forum" alt="FLICKR" align="center" height="auto" width="45%" style="max-height:60px; max-width: 60px;"></td>
          <!-- FLICKR -->
          <td align="center" valign="middle" href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/baltic-development-forum"><img src="http://img.anpdm.com/BalticDevelopmentForum/Asset5x3.png" href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/baltic-development-forum" link="https://www.linkedin.com/company/baltic-development-forum" alt="LINKED IN" align="center" height="auto" width="45%" style="max-height:60px; max-width: 60px;"></td>
          <!-- LINKED IN -->
          
          <td align="center" valign="middle" class="baemailwidthcollapse"><img src="http://customers.anpdm.com/shared/images/pixel.gif"       align="center" link="" height="1" width="20" style="max-height:1; max-width: 20px;"></td>
          <!-- EMPTY --> 
        </tr>
      </table>
  <tr>
    <td><img src="http://customers.anpdm.com/shared/images/pixel.gif" width="1" height="20" style="display:block;"></td>
  </tr>
  </td>
  
  </tr>
  
</table>
```

I would appreciate every little hint or idea on how to get rid of those problems, I believe I have tried everything I am capable of already especially that it works everywhere but some outlook PC clients as yo can see [here](http://www.anpdm.com/newsletterweb/44445E457542445F4771404B59/42445E437341465B447645445C4071).

Sorry for a long post and thank you for help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Outlook doesn't really like it if you run an image dramatically smaller in width than your actual desired output. I could not get your image to tile in the background of the table cell.

Your background code is a bit messed up. I cleaned it up a bit. Try this instead:

```
<!--[if gte mso 9]>
<v:background xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="t">
<v:fill type="tile" src="http://img.anpdm.com/BalticDevelopmentForum/background-100.jpg" color="#333333" />
</v:background>
<![endif]-->
```

Try something like this instead:

```
<div style="background-color:#ff0000;">
  <!--[if gte mso 9]>
  <v:background xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="t">
    <v:fill type="tile" src="http://www.gwally.com/news/photos/catintinfoilhat.jpg" color="#7bceeb"/>
  </v:background>
   <![endif]-->
  <table height="100%" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
    <tr>
  <td valign="top" align="left" background="http://www.gwally.com/news/photos/catintinfoilhat.jpg">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Try formatting your image with this tool: https://backgrounds.cm/

Also, you didn't include your `<head>` information like style sheet and meta tags.

Your table structure as you present it is not very responsive. Half of the email is cut off in IOS devices.

Finally, the maximum size for Outlook is 800px. The closer you come to that width, the more problems you will have with different versions of Outlook.

Good luck.

Comment: thanks for your help! I actually used this tool you sent me. The IOS is not a problem for my design as I have some external classes in a program like "mailchimp", this header is only one module of my newsletter. The only problem is outlook that makes my picture wider or not wide enough depending on something I cannot recognise...